# Protected Variable Error with Workbench 3.0

Tags: warning-messages, symbols, workbench, variable

I have Wolfram Workbench 3.0, build 78, with Mathematica 10.4 as the front end. I am using Windows 10. I am trying to run a simple test source code test.m:

```
fun[x_] := x^2;
```

I have an empty notebook file called test.nb in the project for running this source code. However, when I run test.nb, I receive the following output in the console window:

```
-------------------    
Start Run Session
Connected

Protect::locked: Symbol False is locked.

Set::wrsym: Symbol False is Protected.

Protect::locked: Symbol False is locked.

Set::wrsym: Symbol False is Protected.

Protect::locked: Symbol False is locked.

General::stop: Further output of Protect::locked will be suppressed during this calculation.

Set::wrsym: Symbol False is Protected.

General::stop: Further output of Set::wrsym will be suppressed during this calculation.
Loading
 test.m
Initialization Complete
```

I do not believe there is anything in my code to cause this error, though the error does not seem to prevent the code from running. There are further problems I am having with Workbench, but I feel that I need to address this simple issue first. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance that you had assigned a value to `fun` before, and that value was not cleared?

Comment: Do you mean Workbench 2.0?

Comment: I mean 3.0 (which is still under development, but was provided to me because 2.0 did not work with Mathematica 10.4.) I have tried clearing all variables beforehand (using CleanSlate[] and other methods), to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tech support was able to reproduce the error.

According to them, the error occurred because "the process was not stopped before trying to compile again after adding a new function. To prevent those error messages, remember to click on the Stop button on the bottom right of the program, before compiling again."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize I needed to use the Stop button. Other problems with WB 3.0 may remain, but it appears that this one is solved.